# How do I run a Google Calendar app on B&N Nook Simple Touch?

Tags: nook-simple-touch

How do I run a Google Calendar app on B&N Nook Simple Touch?

I never had a Nook, but I'm interested in buying it to use as a dedicated e-ink wall calendar; I heard it can run Google Calendar; if it indeed does, then all I need is to run it once and leave it alone, given the screensaver is disabled. Making it autorun on startup would be even better.

I have asked about disabling the screensaver [elsewhere](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/74882/how-do-i-disable-screensaver-on-bn-nook-simple-touch).

Answer (score -1):

Root it by flashing one of images available on the net. Lifehacker has simewhat old instructions which worked for me. GCal runs fine it seems, but I have pretty annoying graphical glitch which I'm sure is solvable. I used NookManager image IIRC